# Fill HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm going nuts over this table.
In this page I'm supposed to show all the orders made by an user and the code is basically the same I used in another page, but the the PHP code won't freaking fill the HTML table.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Your orders</h1>
    <table width = "550px" height = "300px" border="2" >
    <tr bgcolor="#5f9ea0">
     <td>Videogame</td>
     <td>Price</td>
     <td>Payment</td>
     <td>Date</td>
    <td>Delete order</td>
    <td>Game received</td>
  </tr>

  <?php
     $conn=pg_connect('dbname=project user=project password=project');
     $user=$_SESSION['Userdata']['username'];
     $query="SELECT o.IDOrder, v.Title, o.price, o.paymenttype, o.date FROM negozio_vg.order o INNER JOIN negozio_vg.videogame v ON o.videogame=vIDVideogame WHERE username='$user' ORDER BY o.date";
     $result=pg_query($conn,$query);
     while ($rows=pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><a href='orderhandler.php'>Delete</a></td><td><a href='orderhandler.php'>Confirm</a></td></tr>",  $rows['title'], $rows['price'],$rows['paymenttype'],$rows['date']);
     }
     ?>
 </table>
  <form action="homeUser.php">
     <input type="submit" value="Ritorna al menu">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm seriously going nuts, because, as I said, I used the same code in another page.
Even worse, the query actually works, and so does the while loop (I tried using an echo instead of a printf and it printed the whole order list)
Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to `echo` the results?!?

Comment: `echo $query` and then feed the query directly into your DB. That will prove whether the query is correct.

Comment: As I said, I also echoed all the results and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 placeholders and provide only 4 values. It's possible the error is either suppressed or it's not displaying in the HTML. Regardless, either remove an `%s` or add another substitution value `$rows['some_column_name']`

Comment: I can't believe it, I simply used 5 placeholders instead of 4, I'm such an idiot.
Thanks  a lot man, I've been wasting the past 2 days over this, it's so awkward!